# Turn NA's into self-loops in igraph

Tags: r, igraph

I do have a directed network with a lot of NA's for a couple of "targets". 
The original dataframe "df2_net" looks like...

```
from      to    Attribute
<int>    <int>    <int>
 5       NA    12120
 6       NA    12210
 3       NA    12300
 6       NA    12310
 5       6     12310
 3       5     12310
```

if I generate the network in a straight forward way:

```
g <- graph.data.frame(df2_net, directed = T)
```

I get the error: `In graph.data.frame(df2_net, directed = T) :
  In d' NA' elements were replaced with string "NA"`

I don't want to just clean things up (`df2_net_clean <- na.omit(df2_net)`)

I would rather want to have the NA's as a kind of self-loop for the "from" variables.

Comment: Why don't you just overwrite the NA value with that in the `from` column? `df2_net[is.na(df2_net$to)]$to <- df2_net$from` ?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion!  Now I do get the error: [Error in <-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, is.na(df2_net$to), value = c(5L,  : 
  duplicate subscripts for columns]

Comment: I didn't test my code before suggesting it, and just wanted to give you a general direction. It seems like @divibisan has taken the extra step of making it a working piece of code :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With credit to @Merik for the suggestion, you can just replace the values of `to` with the value of `from` for all rows where `to` is NA:

```
df2_net[is.na(df2_net $to), 'to'] <- df2_net[is.na(df2_net$to), 'from']
```